# Resource Group Location vs. Tenant Region

Tags: azure, networking, cloud, multi-tenant, globalization

I have been tasked with building a PoC in Azure to "simulate" a future global deployment where data transfer time is important factor. The actual deployment will be using fully on-prem resources. So, as odd as it sounds, I am looking for the worse performance possible between the two options.

Architecture A (single tenant):

1. Create a single Azure tenant in the US region
2. Create a Resource Group with a US-based location
3. Create another Resource Group with an EU-based location

Architecture B (dual tenant):

1. Create an Azure tenant in the US region with a US-based RG
2. Create an entirely separate Azure tenant in an EU region with a EU-based RG

Would the dual-tenant structure above make any measurable difference one way or the other from the single-tenant (assuming all vNetwork, VMs, etc are identical)? I am thinking the single-tenant setup would be faster since (presumably) the traffic never leaves the Azure Service Fabric. But that's just speculation.

Comment: You can take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tenant-type). Not sure AAD data and Azure Service data in the same data center of the same region. But I think you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I got back from a colleague. She is (obviously) far more versed in Azure IaaS than I am. Answer #3 below indicates that the closest analog to the client MPLS connection is via VPN/ER. Not really worth the cost but still good to know.

> 1. Can a single subscription be used to provision US and European region located resources?  **Yes**
> 2. Can resources in US and European located regions be managed from a US based portal? **Yes**
> 3. When allowing resources in US and European located regions communicate with one another what are our options? A couple primary ways...
>
>    - *Intra-regional (tenant to tenant:region to region)*
>        Communications can be provisioned to travel across the Microsoft Azure
>        backbone.  It never hits the open Internet.
>    - *VPN or Express Route:*
>        Travels either the open internet or a private in TLS like route from
>        one region to another. However express route, the mpls like option,
>        does require advanced routing (BGP) and dedicated circuits at I other
>        point from different connectivity providers. Also, expensive.